# How to choose between shared and static library?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, sfml

I'm trying to run the standard example from the SFML Library in Linux. I have download the Rep. from Github, build and install it with CMake. I have build 2 Libraries for static/shared debug, and 2 Libraries for static/shared Release.

The problem now, I don't know much about compiling in the Terminal. I use the commands I found on the SFML Website:

> g++ -c test.cpp
>
> g++ test.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

that works. I can run my SFML Application by ./sfml-app and double-click. But other people who (who have not installed SFML) using Linux cant. And I think it's because the compiler does not use the static libraries. Of course - how he could?  It's not written in the command. But I also don't know how to write it.

The name of the static-release libraries is for example

> libsfml-graphics-s.a
>
> libsfml-window-s.a
>
> libsfml-system-s.a

what must I write in g++, that he is using this libs when he link the stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link your program against the static versions of the libraries, you would do the following:

```
g++ test.o -o sfml-app libsfml-graphics-s.a libsfml-window-s.a libsfml-system-s.a
```

*(Assuming, of course, that these files are in your local directory.)*

Comment: First thanks four your answer. But the problem is not solved. If i do this, he said he cant find libsfml-graphics-s.a and the others. But they definitly existing in usr/local/lib and cmake also said they are installed.

Comment: Then you would have to add /usr/local/lib/ before each of the three files: g++ test.o -o sfml-app /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.a ...

Comment: g++ test.o -o sfml-app /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics-s.a /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window-s.a /usr/local/lib/libsfml-system-s.a

results in a lot of errors.

Comment: What are the errors?  Are they related to the files not being found, or something else?

Comment: Its a lot, this are just some:

GlxContext.cpp:(.text+0x555): undefined reference to `glXGetConfig'
GlxContext.cpp:(.text+0x56b): undefined reference to `glXGetConfig'
GlxContext.cpp:(.text+0x57f): undefined reference to `glXGetConfig'
GlxContext.cpp:(.text+0x595): undefined reference to `glXGetConfig'
GlxContext.cpp:(.text+0x5bb): undefined reference to `XFree'


I know this error, i have this in the past in Code::Blocks. Thats one reason why i dont use IDE's any more ^^

Comment: Those errors in particular occur because the static libraries themselves rely on other libraries - libGL in this case.  You can add -lGL to your command.  There may be many others.

Comment: Thank you. i choose now  to dont link static. When i want to share the stuff i will read about the paketmanager >_>  But Thanks for your Help !